# Using numpy.argpartition

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I'm trying to obtain the top N larges values of an array.

For example:

```
total_A = [0. 0. 30. 0. 20. 58. 0. 0. 31. 0. 0. 0. 398. 132. 0. 0. 316. 0.]
```

Using this:

```
top_A = numpy.argpartition(total_A, -18, axis=None)[-18:]
```

I get:

```
[(top_A[i], numpy.round(total_A[top_A[i]])) for i in top_A]

[(0, 0.0),
 (1, 0.0),
 (2, 30.0),
 (3, 0.0),
 (4, 20.0),
 (5, 58.0),
 (6, 0.0),
 (7, 0.0),
 (8, 31.0),
 (9, 0.0),
 (10, 0.0),
 (11, 0.0),
 (12, 398.0),
 (13, 132.0),
 (14, 0.0),
 (15, 0.0),
 (16, 316.0),
 (17, 0.0)]
```

Which is clearly just my input array order.
Also, if I try this:

```
top_A = numpy.argpartition(total_A, -10, axis=None)[-10:]
```

I receive:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-c457841cdbf1> in <module>()
     16 
     17 print 'Top categories for input matrix A:'
---> 18 [(top_A[i], numpy.round(total_A[top_A[i]])) for i in top_A]
```

I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Comment: In your first example, the input has 18 elements, so of course the output contains all the values in the array.  The code shown in the traceback in the second example doesn't match the code that you say causes it.

Comment: The code shown as line 18 in the traceback should probably be changed to `[(i, numpy.round(total_A[i])) for i in top_A]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
[(top_A[i], numpy.round(total_A[top_A[i]])) for i in top_A]
```

should be simplified to

```
[(i, numpy.round(total_A[i])) for i in top_A]
```

The values in `top_A` are the indices into `total_A`.

For example,

```
In [318]: a = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Get the indices of the 3 largest values:

```
In [319]: p = np.argpartition(a, -3)[-3:]

In [320]: p
Out[320]: array([3, 8, 4])
```

Show the 3 largest values:

```
In [321]: a[p]
Out[321]: array([7, 8, 9])
```

Show the tuples containing the indices and the corresponding values:

```
In [322]: [(i, a[i]) for i in p]
Out[322]: [(3, 7), (8, 8), (4, 9)]
```

Comment: And for completeness... how about the lowest k? I find it very strange how partition works...

Comment: @PascalVKooten  argpartition does not give your sorted indices at all, but rather N indices that are bigger than the rest. It is really useful when you work with ultra-big arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If I've got what you mean, you need to try something like this:

```
A[numpy.argpartition(A, A.size - N)][-N:]
```

To get N large valuese of array A.